# Add parsed GeoJSON points to OpenLayers and make them Clickable

Tags: openlayers

I have points layer, displayed in OpenLayers map. I want to make them clickable, so when I click on every point I get the property I want (ex: coordinates).

I'm newbie in OpenLayers and don't know where to start from.

[image: Points :]

Here is my code :

```
map.on("pointermove", function (evt) {
    var hit = this.forEachFeatureAtPixel(evt.pixel, function(feature, layer) {
        return true;
    }); 
    if (hit) {
        this.getTargetElement().style.cursor = 'pointer';

        //click event
        map.on('singleclick', function (event) {
        var outpout = event.coordinate; 
        console.log(outpout);

}); 

    } else {
        this.getTargetElement().style.cursor = '';
    }
});
```

when I click on  a point I get the coordinates of all the points

Comment: You should add some of your code, as of what you have now. And where should you start from? From examples https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/ and documentation https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/

Comment: I updated the post , please take a look

Comment: Your are processing every click on the map without filtering it, as you have correctly done with `pointermove` event. Have a look at this example how it should be done: https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/vector-layer.html